# how to pass variable to destination of google map

Tags: google-maps

I want to pass a variable to destination of get direction of google map:

```
var contentString =address + '<a href="http://www.google.com/maps?'+'daddr=**abcd**" target="_blank">get Directions</a>';
```

here parameter `daddr` will vary for every post, so in abcd i need to pass a variable which holds address.

Please suggest how can i achieve this.

Comment: `var abcd = encodeURI('your address');`

Comment: I think you may have to give a little context for your problem. I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do

Comment: to clarify the question, I  have an address variable which holds complete addres. Say i have it in $abcd="800 Docklands, Melbourne".  now i want to pass this variable to daddr.  In my website this address will change with every post, hence i need to pass it at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var contentString = address + '<a href="http://www.google.com/maps?daddr=' + encodeURI(abcd) + '" target="_blank">get Directions</a>';
```